# tkinter help: difference between "master" and "root" keywords in this code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning Tkinter and trying to understand OOP concepts. I came across this code online:

```
class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Greet", command=self.greet)
        self.greet_button.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This code worked perfectly, and I understand the widget features and what they do, however, I edited the code slightly as follows:

```
class Timer:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title = ("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="first GUI")
        self.label.pack()

        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Greet", command=self.greet)
        self.greet_button.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")

master = Tk()
my_gui = Timer(master)
master.mainloop()
```

To my surprise, this code also worked perfectly. My question is, what is the difference using 'master' rather than 'root'? what is the 'master' keywords purpose in the code? From what I understand, 'self' is similar to the 'this' keyword in Java, so I'm assuming self and master aren't the same?

Thanks in advance for your help guys! Apologies if what I'm asking wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Neither `master` nor `root` are keywords. They are simply variables of someones choosing. They could be anything which is distinct. Also `self` is similar, but it is a very strong convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any difference between whether you call it "master" or "root". People call it "root" because Tkinter widgets are placed in a tree so part of that would be a "root". People would call it "master" because all widgets have a parents they go to or also a master. So you could call it anything. I hope this answers helps

Answer (score 3):

`master` and `root` are not keywords, they are metasyntactic variables, and don't mean anything special to the compiler. This code works perfectly fine as well:

```
class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, chickens):
        self.chickens = chickens
        chickens.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(chickens, text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.greet_button = Button(chickens, text="Greet", command=self.greet)
        self.greet_button.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(chickens, text="Close", command=chickens.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")

stackoverflow = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(stackoverflow)
stackoverflow.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: oh haha, that makes sense! so in your case, does 'chickens' refer to the parent window? is it sorta just a way to ensure the code knows which window you want a button or label to be placed in?

Comment: Yes. `stackoverflow` is the new Tkinter window, and it is being passed to the `MyFirstGUI` class using the argument `chickens`. And you are correct that the variable is being used so Tkinter knows where to put things.